# Calling of Code Behind method from ajax function Jquery not working

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

I have the following JQuery in my aspx page to call the Code behind function

```
onDelete: function (item) {
      //Some Code
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'Page_Name.aspx/callmethod',
           data: "{}",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json"
       });
    }
```

I am calling the below Method

```
[WebMethod]
public static void callmethod()
{
    Page_Name call = new Page_Name();
    call.Function();
    call.Function_Structure();
    call.Function_items_Structure();
    call.OClear();
    call.PClear();
    call.IClear();
}
```

I had tried in many ways but its not working kindly any one point me what could be wrong here

Comment: have you checked console for errors?

Comment: Not sure, but is it valid to specify a return datatype, but not return anything? I'd expect your ajax call to complain about such a thing.

Comment: Also, do I understand correctly that by `call.pnlCH.Visible = false;`, you are trying to set the ASP.Net form element's attributes via an Ajax call? That won't work. If ASP.Net needs to re-render the controls, you'll need a postback, not an Ajax call.

Comment: I had removed the `call.pnlCH.Visible = false;
call.pnlPdtl.Visible = false;` in my code

Comment: @Rajesh May i ask it's not working means ? Can you narrow it down ? Are you getting an error or does your function calls your method or not or you are getting any error in your code behind method?

Comment: @SurajSingh I am not getting any error in Code behind in the Jquery I am getting **Internal Server Error**

Comment: @Rajesh Try your `data` in function as {} or just don't use data because you are not sending any parameters, "{}" will be counted as a string which might throw error. Please check and let me know.

Comment: @SurajSingh Thanks for your Suggestion I had removed the `data: "{}", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json" ` three lines from my code and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Rajesh I am adding it as answer then .

Comment: @SurajSingh I had accepted your Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `{}` for your data, `"{}"` will be considered as string or don't include data parameter if you are not sending any parameters.

```
onDelete: function (item) {
      //Some Code
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'Page_Name.aspx/callmethod',
          // data: "{}",
              data: {}, 
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json"
       });
    }
```

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to accomplish is inherently impossible. In your webmethod, I see the following lines:

```
call.pnlCH.Visible = false;
call.pnlPdtl.Visible = false;
```

You're trying to change the attributes of your ASP.Net form elements, but without using a postback operation. If you do not have a postback, ASP.Net will not re-render your page for you! It will only return what you tell the webmethod to return, which in your case is `void`.

There are two ways to fix this, I'm not sure which it is you want:

**Option 1 - No ASP.Net interference needed**

If you only want to change some element's visibility, you could do that via jQuery, you don't need your backend for that.

```
$("#myElement").show();
$("#myElement").hide();
```

For ASP.Net controls, you'll want to know the clientId.

```
var clientId = <%= pnlCH.ClientID %>;

$("#" + clientID).hide();
```

**Option 2 - ASP.Net is needed**

If you need your backend code for this (e.g. to look something up from the database, or any other good reason), doing it purely via jQuery isn't going to help. In this case, what you'll want to be doing is perform a *regular postback scenario*.

Having the page post back means that ASP.Net will render your page again. Any change you make to the form elements will then be rendered.

It's important to note here that a postback is required to have ASP.Net re-render your page.

So all in all, I'm not sure which way you want/need to go with this. But your current approach, while syntactically valid, will simply not work because of how ASP.Net and client-side asynchronous calls work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an error function to your $ajax call, and see what errors come back.

```
data: {},
dataType: "json",
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
   // debug here
   alert(jqXHR);
},
success: function() ...
```

Comment: The Error I am getting is **Internal Server Error**